# How to disable repetitive keydown in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keydown

I have a same problem like this guy [How to disable repetitive keydown in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098901/how-to-disable-repetitive-keydown-in-jquery) , it's just that I'm not using jQuery so I'm having hard time translating it to "pure" JavaScript, anyways I have set `switch`-case of some keys and when I press and hold right arrow key my div is flying. Also if it's not a problem can you tell me what would be the easiest way to stop div movement when I let the right arrow key go, do I have to make a new switch case with `clearInterval` or?

```
switch (keyPressed) {
    case 39:
        setInterval(movFwr, 50);
        break;
}

function movFwr() {
    if (currPos == 1000) {
        a.style.left = 1000 + "px";
    } else currPos += 10;
    a.style.left = trenutnaPozicija + "px";
}
```

I'm sorry guys, I've been busy a bit, I'm testing all possibilities and so far I have seen some interesting suggestions. I'll test em all these days and then rate of what ever is that you do on this site. Great community I must say. Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: what you wanna do exactly?setinterval is always a bad solution

Comment: Modern JavaScript supports `event.repeat`: `function onKeyDown({ repeat }) { if (repeat) return }`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick;

```
var down = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
    if(down) return;
    down = true;

    // your magic code here
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    down = false;
}, false);
```

Comment: This is the simplest, most universal solution.

Comment: Why create and manage another variable when there is a "repeat" boolean property on the event, which is set to true once the event starts to repeat.

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.repeat) return;

  // TODO...
}, false);

Comment: @DDN-Shep Well, `Status Obsolete`... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat

Comment: Still relevant in 2019, but it's definitely better to, rather than `down = false` to use `const isDown = {}` and then setting/checking `isDown[evt.key]` as boolean instead (also, certainly today, but even in 2013, the capture flag was mostly useless, so no need to specify it)

Comment: The status is obsolete, but where is the replacement? MDN says that DOM3 spec for KeyBoardEvent itself is obsolete, and that the draft spec at https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-keyboardevents is the current one. But that includes repeat. So honestly, its a bit confusing.

Comment: This code doesn’t always work as it should be: if a key is held and another key is pressed at the same time, it will only take account of the first key. For example, if you make a game where you control your character with the four arrow keys, the diagonal will be impossible.

Comment: @DDN-Shep Could you post that as an answer? I can’t find a good example with the repeat property on the Internet.

Comment: @BarryCap the repeat property *on the event object* passed in the callback..

Answer (score 2):

I would record the time and prevent action unless enough time has passed, for example using [`Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

```
var lastPress = 0;

function myListener() {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (now - lastPress < 1000) return; // less than a second ago, stop
    lastPress = now;
    // continue..
}
```

---

This can be made into a more generic function

```
function restrict(func, minDuration) {
    var lastPress = 0;
    return function () {
        var now = Date.now();
        if (now - lastPress < minDuration) return; // or `throw`
        lastPress = now;
        return func.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
// now, for example
foo = function () {console.log('foo');};
bar = restrict(foo, 200); // only permit up to once every 200ms
bar(); // logs "foo"
bar(); // void as less than 200ms passed
```

Comment: This could possibly block different keys from being pressed if they are pressed during the 1 second in the first code, or quicker then the minDuration in the second.

Comment: True, depending on where this break in the code is employed, for example if it's all keys or only after you've already established which key.

Comment: This one helped me with 1 other problem I had (had to modify it a bit) :D Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To ignore key events caused by key repeats, keep track of which keys are pressed during the `keydown` and `keyup` events.

```
var pressedKeys = [];
function keydownHandler(e) {
    var isRepeating = !!pressedKeys[e.keyCode];
    pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case !isRepeating && 39:
            // do something when the right arrow key is pressed, but not repeating
            break;
    }
}
function keyupHandler(e) {
    pressedkeys[e.keyCode] = false;
}
```

To stop your div moving, you could keep track of the interval ids in an array, and clear the interval during the `keyup` event with something like `clearInterval(intervalIds[e.keyCode])`, but I'd probably switch to using `setTimeout()` and checking whether they key is down instead.  That way, you don't have to keep track of another variable.

```
var pressedKeys = [];
function keydownHandler(e) {
    var isRepeating = !!pressedKeys[e.keyCode];
    pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case !isRepeating && 39:
            movFwr();
            break;
    }
}
function keyupHandler(e) {
    pressedkeys[e.keyCode] = false;
}
function movFwr() {
    if (pressedKeys[39] && currPos < 1000) {
        currPos += 10;
        a.style.left = currPos + "px";
        setTimeout(movFwr, 50);
    }
}
```

This way, you also automatically stop repeating the function as soon as the div reaches the right edge, instead of waiting for the user to release the arrow key.

Answer (score 0):

Track the last key pressed, if its the same as current ignore it by returning, and use `clearInterval` to stop the intervals

```
//global variables
var lastKey = 0;
var moveTimer = [];

//in keydown function
if(lastKey == keyPressed)
    return;
switch (keyPressed) {
    case 39:
        lastKey = keyPressed
        moveTimer[keyPressed] = setInterval(movFwr, 50);
        break;
}


//in a onkey up function
lastKey = null;
if(typeof(moveTimer[keyPressed]) != "undefined")
    clearInterval(moveTimer[keyPressed]);
```